# Java String variable becomes corrupt at runtime

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hey all I've got a weird bug in a small Java program I'm writing for a school project. I am well aware of how sloppy the code is (it is still a work in progress), but anyway, somehow my string variable "year" becomes corrupted after breaking out of a loop. I am using Java with Mapreduce and hadoop to count unigrams and bigrams and sort them by year/author. Using print statements, I have determined that "year" is indeed set when I set it equal to temp, but any time after the loop it is set in, the variable is corrupted somehow. The year number becomes replaced with a huge amount of whitespace (at least that's how it appears in the console). I have tried setting `year=year.trim()` and using the regex `year=year.replaceAll("[^0-9]","")`, neither works. Anybody have any ideas? 
I have only included the map class, as that is where the problem is. Also it should be noted that the text files being parsed are files from Project Gutenberg.I am working with a small sample of about 40 random texts from the project.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text(); 
    public synchronized void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        line = line.replaceAll("[^0-9a-z\\s-*]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " "); 
        String year=""; // variable to hold date -- somehow this gets cleared out before I need it
        String temp=""; // variable to hold each token
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line); // Splits document into individual words for parsing
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

            temp = tokenizer.nextToken(); // grab first token of document
            if (temp.equals("***")) // hit first triple star, break out and move to next while loop
                break;

            if (temp.equals("release")&&tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){ // if token is "release" followed by "date", extract year
                if (tokenizer.nextToken().equals("date")){
                    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                        temp = tokenizer.nextToken();
                        for (int i = 0; i<temp.length();i++){
                            if (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0))){
                                if (temp.length()>3||Integer.parseInt(temp)>=40){
                                    year = temp; // set year = token if token is a number greater than 40 or has >3 digits
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!year.equals("")){ //if date isn't an empty string, it means we have date and break
                            break;            // out of first while loop
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n"+year+"\n");// year will still print here
                }
            } // but it is gone if I try to print past this point 
        }

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){ // keep grabbing tokens until hit another "***", then break and
            temp = tokenizer.nextToken();  // can begin counting unigrams/bigrams
            if (temp.equals("***"))
                break;
        }

        line = line.substring(line.indexOf(temp)); // form a new document starting from location of previous "***"
        line = line.replaceAll("[^a-z\\s-]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("-+", "-");  /*Many calls to remove excess whitespace and punctuation from entire document*/
        line = line.replaceAll(" - ", " "); 
        line = line.replaceAll("- ", " "); 
        line = line.replaceAll(" -", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

        StringTokenizer toke = new StringTokenizer(line); //start a new tokenizer with re-formatted file

        while(toke.hasMoreTokens()){//continue to grab tokens until EOF
            temp = toke.nextToken();
            //System.out.println(date);

            if (temp.charAt(0)=='-')
                temp = temp.substring(1);//if word starts or ends with hyphen, remove it
            if (temp.length()>1&&temp.charAt(temp.length()-1)=='-')
                temp = temp.replace('-', ' ');

            if ((!temp.equals(" "))){
                word.set(temp+"\t"+year);   
                context.write(word,one); 
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The only way to tell would be to step through the code in your debugger and see which line changes the `year` variable.

Comment: you should give us your input string! (also expected output)

Answer (score 1):

You have `year = temp` in your code. It seems it depends on your input what you get there.

Possible bug:

```
for (int i = 0; i<temp.length();i++){
    if (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0))){
```

IMHO you mean `i` instead of 0 in charAt:

```
for (int i = 0; i<temp.length();i++){
    if (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(i))){
```

Also consider not to use StringTokenizer:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.
>
> The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be
>   used to break up a string into its basic tokens:
>
> ```
>  String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
>  for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
>      System.out.println(result[x]);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Found your white space...

The 2 statements that print out the year variable add a couple newlines:

```
System.out.println("\n"+year+"\n")
```

or a tab:

```
word.set(temp+"\t"+year);   
context.write(word,one);
```

Try removing the \n and \t.